# how do i maintain the content of a text box after post back

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a text box which get its value from htmlcontrol (div)onclik by javascript.
am able to get the value into the text box but the value gets disappeared on postback.
how do I maintain the value in the text box after postback? Thanks in advance

```
   //this is my java script
     $(document).on("click", ".productsize", function () {
    var psize = $(this).closest("div").html();
    sessionStorage.setItem("newstor", psize);
   $(document.getElementById('<%=TextBox1.ClientID%>')).val(sessionStorage.getItem("newstor"));
```

Comment: maybe you clear it on post back - can we see your code about it on code behind ?

Comment: please I currently do not have any code associated with the textbox from codebehind but what i have is the htmlcontrol (div) is created dynamically from codebehind on pageload event

Comment: if you set the value, and you see it, and then you do post back, then you get the value on code behind for sure - if not, then you maybe clear it on post back, or not do post back at all

Comment: please come again I dont really get you

Comment: ok I realize the value get disappeared when I set the property of the textbox to readonly  but i also dont want this value to be edited by the user